# Factory for iOS Models on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I'm starting a new project and the I have a really hight testing requirements. The app is very "data intensive" lots of models and models nested.

I'm trying to think a good way to be able to organize and create fake models I'm going to be using to test ViewModels.

I'm looking for something similar to [`factory_bot`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) in Ruby but I can't find anything similar for iOS.

Any advise?

Comment: https://github.com/lucasmedeirosleite/CMFactory - > you need to link against objc code though, not perfect but maybe a help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, (*writing short after Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2*, the static nature of Swift has prevented the development of libraries like [`factory_bot`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) or [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) which instead rely on dynamic features.

The approach I've been taking is to define a builder function in an extension for each of the types that I need to use as fixtures in my test suite.

For example given a `User` model, with an `Address` property, looking like this:

```
struct Address {
  let streetNumber: String
  let street: String
  // ...
}

struct User {
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
  let address: Address
  // ...
}
```

The fixtures would look like this:

```
extension Address {

  static func fixture(
    streetNumber: String = "1",
    street: String = "Infinity Loop"
  ) -> Address {
    return Address(streetNumber: streetNumber, street: street)
  }
}

extension User {

  static func fixture(
    firstName: String = "Jane",
    lastName: String = "Appleseed",
    address: Address = .fixture()
  ) -> User {
    return User(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, address: Address)
  }
}
```

I can get a fixture with only default values for `User` by doing this:

```
let fixtureUser = User.fixture()
// or
let fixtureUser: User = .fixture()
```

I can also provide custom values for as my parameters as I need, like I was using `factory_bot`.

```
let leo = User.fixture(firstName: "Leo")
```

This approach requires work upfront, but once you incur the one-off cost of building the `.fixture()` method, using and modifying them becomes straightforward.

You can nest as many fixtures as you want, although I haven't found a neat way to modify an object deep in the nesting tree without accessing the `.fixture()` for each of its parents.

I wrote in detail about this approach in [this article](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/streamlining-tests-setup-with-fixtures-in-swift/).